# Splitting multiband raster layers using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I'm brand new in python.

I'm using QGIS 2.18.3.
I wrote this script that should read all the dual band raster layers in the canvas and should save each band in a separate way, but it doesn't work.
I presume it will be full of errors.

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

# where to save bands
outputDir = "D:\prova"

import os
lddLrs = qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().layers()

for lyr in lddLrs:
    if (lyr.type()==QgsMapLayer.RasterLayer): 
    os.system("gdal_translate -b 1 "+ str(lyr.source()) + " " + outputDir + " / " + str(lyr.name()) + " _VV.tif"))
    qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer(str(outputDir + "/" + lyr.name() + ".tif"), str(lyr.name() + "_VV.tif"))
    os.system("gdal_translate -b 2 "+ str(lyr.source()) + " " + outputDir + " / " + str(lyr.name()) + " _VH.tif"))
    qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer(str(outputDir + "/" + lyr.name() + ".tif"), str(lyr.name() + "_VH.tif"))
```

Comment: I fixed all errors and now, code works perfectly. Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed all errors and now, it works perfectly. Complete code is below:

```
import sys, os

# where to save bands
outputDir = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data"

lddLrs = iface.legendInterface().layers()

for lyr in lddLrs:
    if (lyr.type() == QgsMapLayer.RasterLayer): 
        cmd1 = "gdal_translate -b 1 "+ lyr.source() + " " + outputDir + "/" + lyr.name() + "_VV.tif"
        os.system(cmd1)
        cmd2 = outputDir + "/" + lyr.name() + "_VV.tif"
        iface.addRasterLayer(cmd2)
        cmd3 = "gdal_translate -b 2 "+ lyr.source() + " " + outputDir + "/" + lyr.name() + "_VH.tif"
        os.system(cmd3)
        cmd4 = outputDir + "/" + lyr.name() + "_VH.tif"
        iface.addRasterLayer(cmd4)
```

I tried it out with a RGB raster. After running the code, bands 1 and 2 were loaded automatically; as it can be observed at next image:

[image]

With Value Tool plugin of QGIS, I corroborated that the splitting was done as expected.

Comment: I apologize, I need to be more skilled to participate to stack exchange. Thank you again